# How can I connect my grill's quick-connect hose to my exterior gas port?

Tags: plumbing, natural-gas

I was wondering if someone could tell what I would need to convert my receptacle to accept my Weber's 3/8 quick connect hose.

Short story being that I purchased an used Weber genesis NG grill since my new condo comes with the NG receptacle on the balcony and being new to this I unsuccessfully tried a couple of times trying to hook it up until I figured out that it is probably too  big for my hose. From what I could measure the the quick connect receptacle seems be a 1/2 inch model, is it as simple as unscrewing the 1/2 quick connect receptacle and replacing it with a 3/8 model or is there more to it? linked example of parts would be appreciated.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: re you trying to connect a Weber PROPANE quick connect to a NG outlet? Natural Gas cannot be used with a propane grill without exchanging the orifices of the grills. NG grill uses low pressure and propane is high pressure.

Comment: @Programmer66 from the OP, "I purchased an used Weber genesis **NG** grill" (emphasis added). I would presume it's a natural gas grill.

Answer (score 3):

Natural gas sources are standardized so you shouldn't have to worry about a new regulator or anything like that.  There are different types of NG connections, but this one was placed for a grill or other "patio appliance" so that shouldn't be a concern.

As far as the quick connect goes, I would follow the instructions on the label and find an actual "Gas~Flo" quick connect.  The management office or maintenance staff might know the best place to get one, or if you get lucky, might have one you can have/buy.  It should be as easy as taking off your current quick connect from the grill and screwing on the new one (using the proper thread sealant).  There's a chance that you might need a standard pipe adapter if your hose threads are different from the quick connect threads, but thats a basic hardware store item (use brass).

Comment: Will do Thanks, I'll try and see if I can reach out to the manufacturer

Comment: Seems all the places the manufacturer are pointing to only sell to gas contractors unfortunately

Comment: I hope the condo management can help.  After all, it’s in their best interest that people hook up grills correctly and safely.  Other brands might fit, but they might also be slightly smaller and not make a good seal.  Just check carefully if you end up using another brand.

Answer (score 2):

@FreeMan pointed out you do have a NG Grill,

Here is a quick connect adapter that seems to do what you want.

Picture from Amazon.

[image]

The link to the adapter:
[3/8 in. adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071HSYWD3)

Look at the photos at the site and see if it has the proper ends that you are trying to connect to.

Comment: Thanks. as I was looking for a quick solution I ended up going to the hardware store and getting a reducer for the 1/2 to 3/8 and then connecting it to a 3/8 quick disconnect that I got seperately